# How to detect if an item is selected and alert its value with this jquery-editable-select plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got a jquery-editable-select plugin from [here](https://github.com/indrimuska/jquery-editable-select)

It doesn't work as a normal select>option> tags. I tried adding many different eventListeners and still have no success. Basically, I want to alert the selected value when one of the options is being selected and also alert the text value when users decide to type it into the text field.

```
<select id="editable-select">
<option>Alfa Romeo</option>
<option>Audi</option>
<option>BMW</option>
<option>Citroen</option>
</select>

$('#editable-select').editableSelect();
```

Please include the plugin js & css files under src folder before you test this.

It should look something like this.
[image]

The plugin turns original HTML to this.
[image]
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin has a Listener

## Listen changes

```
  $('#select')
        .editableSelect()
        .on('select.editable-select', function (e, li) {
            $('#last-selected').html(
                li.val() + '. ' + li.text()
            );
        });
```

[jQuery Editable Select Demo](http://indrimuska.github.io/jquery-editable-select/)

Comment: did you try it @Richard

Comment: I haven't try it. Will try it after dinner. Forgot to tell you that I'm blind.... Thanks for the help